# Why is variable i not incremented in the loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

What's the problem here? I was trying to concatenate two strings.

Here's the full code. Only first string is printed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char s[100],s2[100];
    printf("Enter a String\n");
    scanf("%s",&s);
    printf("Enter second String\n");
    scanf("%s",&s2);
    int i=strlen(s);
    //printf("%d",i);
    int j;


    for(j=0;s2[j]!='\0';++j)
    {
        i+=1;
        s[i]=s2[j];
    }

    printf("%s",s);
}
```

Comment: When the loop starts, the index `i` is the index of the null-terminator of `s`. Now what happens inside the loop when you do `i += 1`? What is the index you start appending the second string? What happens with the null-terminator of the first string? And note that you don't append the terminator of the second string, making that part unterminated.

Comment: For future problems like this, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: 1) `scanf( "%s", s );` can be without `&s`; 2) shorter condition in `for` loop: `for ( j=0; s2[j]; ++j )`; 3) `i+=1` can be added in `for` as well: `for ( j=0; s2[j]; ++j, ++i )`. Or simply use `strcat` instead of loop: `strcat( s, s2 )`.

Answer (score 1):

As already commented, you jump over the terminator of s,
change to

```
for(j=0;s2[j]!='\0';++j)
{
    s[i]=s2[j];
    i+=1;
}
s1[i]='\0'; // terminated after concatenation
```

and you should be there. Keep in mind that if you dont check the length of the resulting string you may overflow the s[100] array.

Answer (score -1):

If you want write this more secure and dont overflow the s variable use this:

```
size_t size = strlen(s) + strlen(s2);
char* result = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * size + 1);
sprintf(result, "%s%s", size);
```

This is simple and safe.
And do it in function to automatic free `s` and `s2`.

Comment: You forgot to add 1 to `size` for the string terminator that will be generated by `sprintf`, and `sprintf` needs two string arguments. Anyway even when fixed this does not concatenate `s2` to `s`.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition. But suppose it is `2`, how would the arithmetic work after the edit? The `1` is added in the wrong place.